# Getting subset of data based on conditional values from two columns

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame called (image attached below) where I need to select rows based on conditional values of two columns. Specifically, I need to select those rows where c1Pos and c2Pos have consecutive values (e.g., 4 and 5, 3 and 2, etc.).

[image]

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
  combined_df_locat_short_cues_consec<-subset(combined_df_color_locat_cues, subset=!(c2Pos==c1Pos+1|c1Pos==c1Pos-1))
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Mikel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace

- `subset=!` with `subset=`
- `c1Pos==c1Pos-1` with `c2Pos==c1Pos-1`

```
combined_df_locat_short_cues_consec<-subset(combined_df_color_locat_cues, subset=(c2Pos==c1Pos+1|c2Pos==c1Pos-1))
```

Comment: Hi Nobukuni, that worked great! On the other hand, I'm trying to do the inverse also, that's it all the trials where c1Pos and c2Pos are not consecutive. In that case, I'd use "subset=!(c2Pos==c1Pos+1|c2Pos==c1Pos-1)), right? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's right. You are welcome!